# Adding/ removing animations in JavaFX

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I'm trying to make an animation of a circle that constantly increases its radius up to a point, and then sets radius back to zero and so on. But I want the user to be able to choose how many of those circles he wants. So my question is, can I do it and then bind it to some text field or combo box so every time user changes it the animation adds/removes itself?

Comment: Please clarify "how many of those circles"- is it number of times the circle increases and decreases its radius or number of distinct circles which do the operation simultaneously?

Comment: @user79161 I meant that I can have multiple circles that increase their size at the same time. Like copies of one animation that are just added in different place on my pane.

Comment: Just keep the animation(s) in a field/suitable data structure. This way you can simply stop them, if you no longer want them to be running. You may also be able to modify the existing animation instead...

Answer (score 0):

What you can here is that you could initiate the animation with a single circle and present the user a textfield to specify the number of circles and a **submit** button(most intuitive way for them to specify their final choice) next to it.

Once the user enters a legitimate value, and presses submit, you can update the number of circle(s) and re-start the animation with the circle(s) increasing in their radius. Note that you might want the rate of change of radii of the circles to be different so that they are not obscuring each other.